# Creating a class that extends Jlabel to draw a string to a panel. Nothing is currently being displayed

Tags: java, swing

I am new to the swing and graphics and am trying to get this to work for drawing a string on a label by making an object class called DrawString. A panel currently pops up with nothing on it. I would like to thank you for any guidance you can give.

```
   package view;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;

    public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        DrawString text = new DrawString();

        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setSize(400, 400);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        text.display("Boo");
        panel.setLocation(((window.getWidth()/2)-(panel.getWidth()/2)), 
        ((window.getHeight()/2)-(panel.getHeight()/2)));
        panel.setSize(200, 200);
        window.add(panel);
        panel.add(text);



    }

}



   package view;

import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JLabel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawString extends JLabel{

    String string;
    Font font = new Font("TimesRoman",Font.PLAIN, 30);

    public DrawString() {
        super();


    }
    public void display(String string){
        this.string=string;
        repaint();
    }
    public void drawString(Graphics comp){
        super.paintComponent(comp);
        Graphics2D g = (Graphics2D) comp;
        g.setFont(font);
        g.drawString(string, JLabel.CENTER, JLabel.CENTER);
    }


}
```

Comment: move you setvisible to end of the component adding line

Comment: Is the JLabel ever use your `string` variable at all when rendering?

Comment: no i added a button and action listener to to try to repaint it at one point but it had no effect

Comment: You don't need to extend `JLabel`; just invoke the label's `setText()` method.

Comment: Amen to what @trashgod just posted. Why are you making things more difficult than they need to be?

Comment: I am learning and experimenting that is all. I am trying to learn what works and what doesn't and why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am learning and experimenting…

It's not clear if you want to experiment with [`JLabel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) or [custom painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/). You might want to start with a working `JLabel#setText()` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056557/230513) or `TextLayout#draw()` [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8282330/230513).