# Event Dispatch Thread - reporting

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, swingworker, event-dispatch-thread

I was wondering, I want to report some form of progress from my swing worker back to the main thread so my interface can be updated with a label that changes as the progress increases, for example

> checking 1/6...
>
> checking 2/6...
>
> ..
>
> ..

I did something similar in c# a while a go but cant remember how so now cant transfer the logic to this java application. Instead of a background worker i am using a swing worker here

Please could someone enlighten me on what i need to research

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "Monitoring" SwingWorker there are

- add [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/beans/PropertyChangeListener.html)
- update `JLabel` from method [process()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#process%28java.util.List%29)

Answer (score 0):

You already have an answer, and probably even solved your problem. But still, it might be worth looking at [my answer on another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565) which contains a snippet which does almost exactly what you are looking for