# Change JProgressBar value, while Thread is running

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, jslider

I want to change the value of a JSlider in a panel, while I'm running a Thread which give's me this value (because of some progress)

So i calculate the progress-value in the Thread, and with a GET-method I fetch the value in the panel and want to set it to the progressbar.

After debugging it, a value is there but the **EDIT:[ JProgressBar ]** don't change his UI.

**Some code:**

```
while(_thread.isAlive()) {
 pb_calc.setValue(_thread.getVal());
 pb_calc.updateUI();
}
```

Comment: Use a `JProgressBar` instead of a `JSlider`.

Comment: sorry, i have a progressbar - look edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- dont use `updateUI`, this method is reserved for `Look and Feel` and `UIManager`
- output from `Background Tasks` should be wrapped into `invokeLater`, more in the tutorial [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)
- better would be invoke `Background` taks from `SwingWorker` or inside `Runnable#Thread`

Comment: can you give me an example what y mean?

Comment: @Christian 'fuzi' Orgler check my profile here, there are examples to my last point

Comment: @Christian'fuzi'Orgler http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565 is an example. The Swing tutorials also contain one (follow the link in the JProgressBar class javadoc ... how convenient is that)