# Long running process, show progress in UI

Tags: java, swing, design-patterns, jprogressbar

I want to trigger a long running background process (coded as a service) from the ui. But I also want to show some progress of that task to the user.

How can I achieve this? (I want to not infringe on decoupling).
Is there a best practice to solve it (combining design-patterns, eg. observer and command)?

Comment: The observer pattern on it's own is already a solution to this kind of problem. The Observee just has to inform observers everytime the progress changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example on how to use just the observer pattern to show
progress in the UI. With JAVA sample code provided:

[Using Observer Pattern to track progress while loading a page](http://www.crjug.org/?q=node/112)

Answer (score 3):

Have look a [JProgressBar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) and changes for progress could be invoked from `Runnable#Thread` or [SwingWorker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565) is another example of a `SwingWorker` to do the heavy work, and to update a `JProgressBar` which is contained in the UI to show the progress to the user