# several times change label text by clicking button in swing not work

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jlabel

I need to change jlabel.text several times by one click button in swing. In this code i need set label text to start before dowork()  function and set to in progress in middle and set it to end after dowork() (status type in jlabel and dowork has long time execution) :

```
 private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
        status.setText("start");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PelakInRFID.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        status.setText("in progress");
        dowork();
       try {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PelakInRFID.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        status.setText("end");

 }
```

In this code status only set to end and start doesn't show.

Comment: Consult the [Progress tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) on how you show progress, or take a look at available examples on SO like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to use a `SwingWorker` instance (in particular its `doInBackground` method) to do what you are currently doing in `doWork` on a different thread than the main UI thread. The way it's written, your listener method is bound to freeze the user interface during execution, which, as you said, can be a long time, resulting in a bad user experience.

Change to `JLabel` text can happen in three different places: first, just before invoking `execute` on (i.e. starting) the `SwingWorker`; second, using the `publish`/`process` mechanism that `SwingWorker` makes available to publish intermediate results on the user interface; third, in the `done` method, which is called again on the UI thread as soon as the `SwingWorker` has finished the execution of its `doInBackground` method.

References: Oracle's tutorial on [worker threads and `SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), JavaDoc API [documentation of the `SwingWorker` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html).

Answer (score 2):

Never, NEVER use `Thread.sleep`, `Thead.yield` in the `ETD`

Never, NEVER perform any blocking actions in the `ETD`, such as extended IO or data processing

The reason that the label is not changing is because you are stalling/blocking the `ETD`, preventing it from processing any repaint requests.

Check out [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) & [The Event Dispatching Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)