# How to show processing info. in program?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I have created a GUI having one `JButton` and some other components.  When I click the button, some back end processing is involved which takes nearly 10-12seconds.

How should I represent it graphically?

Comment: I have tried some splash screen kind of.But i am getting it only when my application is loading initially.I want to represent some thing like splash screen showing "processing...."info

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916721/java-swing-update-label/8917565#8917565)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`JProgressBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JProgressBar.html) for displaying the progress of the task.

[image: JProgressBar at 52%]

Put it inside a non-modal dialog that has a 'cancel' button (if the long running operation can safely be cancelled).

Be sure to obey the [rules of the EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) by performing the long running task 'off the EDT', while the updates to the progress bar are done 'on the EDT'.  The [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) offers easy access to both.