# Can't addElement to JList

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, jlist, event-dispatch-thread

I know this isn't the only question about filling JLists, but I didn't find the answer in another SO thread.

I've used the Netbeans GUI builder to create my GUI. The JList is added to a scrollpane, if I hardcode the content of the JList everything is showed fine.

```
jList1.setModel(new javax.swing.AbstractListModel() { 
public String[] strings = {"1", "2", "etc..."}; 
@Override 
  public int getSize() { 
  return strings.length; 
} 

@Override 
   public Object getElementAt(int i) { 
   return strings[i]; 
} 
});
```

But if I try to add items dynamically via `SwingWorker`, nothing appears.

```
JList jList1 = new javax.swing.JList();
DefaultListModel info = new DefaultListModel();
....
jList1.setModel(info);

....
public void FillList(final String subject) {

    worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() {
            info.addElement(subject);

            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

I just want to show the subjects in the JList for visual purposes, the rest is done in the background.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the code is executing? A little debuggin or even a `System.out.println` well placed can give a lot of perspective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I am sure it is executing. If place this line: `System.out.println(info.getSize());` in `doInBackground()` the size of the `ListModel` increments.

Comment: When you use dynamic content, are you storing the dynamic content in the array "strings"?

Comment: Oops I forgot to change the `getSize()` and `getElementAt()` methods. But in another class I retrieve certain messages from an e-mail account, from which I take the subject and call `FillList(subject)` so FillList gets called for every e-mail. I just want to show the subjects in the JList for visual purposes, the rest is done in the background.

Comment: **WRONG** - you _must not_ change a component (neither any of its properties nor the underlying model) from the worker thread, that is **NOT** in doInBackground()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Swing is single threaded and all output to the visible GUI must be done on EDT
- you have an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)
- output from [SwingWorkers methods doInBackground()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/simple.html) doesn't [notified `EventDispatchThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968)
- then any changes in [ListModel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#mutable) isn't visible in the Swing GUI
- have to override [`publish()` or `process()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html), these two methods quite quarenteed that output will be doe on EDT

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Going to put some time in reading those links, thanks for your help.