# Simple Java GUI as a popup window and drop-down menu

Tags: java, swing, popup, jcombobox, joptionpane

I never had to write GUI in java. This time I can also skip it and use `args` as UI (user interface). 
But I wonder if there is a simple way to create a small GUI to let the user select one of the options.
In other words, to implement the `askUser()` function where user can select from a drop-down menu and press "ok".
I spend some time learning this topic, but not even sure that I know which type of GUI i need for this task. JFrame? JPanel? Jmenu? Thanks.

Here is an example of the desired function.

```
package trygui;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] choices = new String[]{"cats", "dogs"};
        int choice = askUser(choices);
        System.out.println("selected: " + choices[choice]);
    }

    static int askUser(String[] choices) {
        // create pop-up dialog
        return 0;
    }
}
```

**Update**: I use Netbeans, if this can make difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The simplest option would be to use the `JOptionPane` API

[image]

```
public class TestOptionPane03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestOptionPane03();
    }

    public TestOptionPane03() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.add(new JLabel("Please make a selection:"));
                DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
                model.addElement("Chocolate");
                model.addElement("Strewberry");
                model.addElement("Vanilla");
                JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
                panel.add(comboBox);

                int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Flavor", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
                switch (result) {
                    case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                        System.out.println("You selected " + comboBox.getSelectedItem());
                        break;
                }

            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can find out more by having a read through [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

**UPDATED with feedback**

```
public class TestOptionPane03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String choice = ask("Chocolate", "Strewberry", "Vanilla");
        System.out.println("You choose " + choice);
    }

    public static String ask(final String... values) {

        String result = null;

        if (EventQueue.isDispatchThread()) {

            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.add(new JLabel("Please make a selection:"));
            DefaultComboBoxModel model = new DefaultComboBoxModel();
            for (String value : values) {
                model.addElement(value);
            }
            JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(model);
            panel.add(comboBox);

            int iResult = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, panel, "Flavor", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);
            switch (iResult) {
                case JOptionPane.OK_OPTION:
                    result = (String) comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                    break;
            }

        } else {

            Response response = new Response(values);
            try {
                SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(response);
                result = response.getResponse();
            } catch (InterruptedException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        return result;

    }

    public static class Response implements Runnable {

        private String[] values;
        private String response;

        public Response(String... values) {
            this.values = values;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            response = ask(values);
        }

        public String getResponse() {
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But I needed the result in the main(). I found a solution using JOptionPane. But just to understand, how could I get the resulting `String` in the main() if I use your solution?

Comment: The problem you have there is your attempting to access the UI from out side the Event Dispatching Thread (as `main` is not launched within the EDT).  This brings a number of issues.  Check update for possible solution.  The real solution would be to use `SwingUtilties#invokeLater` in the `main` method to get you into the EDT and continue launching the remainder of you application there

Comment: @MadProgrammer [for notified about initial thread in another answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to create a Swing GUI, using an IDE like NetBeans gives you the simplicity of using a [WYSIWYG gui designer](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html), so you can just drag and drop your GUI elements into place, and then add your logic code around the GUI code that [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/) outputs.

It certainly isn't something to rely on to "build the gui for you", but it does do a great job of setting up the foundation for you to work with. You can also learn a lot about Swing just by reading through and working with the code that NetBeans generates for the GUI.

I find this a great accelerator in getting started designing Swing apps.

Answer (score 2):

After asking I found this solution. To make it simpler, the `askUser()` returns `String`.

```
package trygui;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] choices = new String[]{"cats", "dogs"};
        String choice = askUser(choices);
        System.out.println("selected: " + choice);
    }

    static String askUser(String[] choices) {
        String s = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "make your choice",
                "Try GUI",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                null,
                choices,
                choices[0]);
        return s;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: NEVER create/modify ANY UI COMPONENT out side the Event Dispatching Thread, it is bad practice and will lead you down a slippery slope of frustration and baldness (as you tear your hair out)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, I read about EDT in wiki, and I must admit that I don't understand what troubles can this solution cause for such a simple task. Can you give an example in which it fails?

Comment: The main problem is you can end up with dirty paints or mutate exceptions (as a model is begin updated by two threads simultaneously).  While it's a simple example, it's bad practice, a practice that if you don't take the pains to eradicate, will come back and haunt you in ways which are difficult to debug (hello Thread race and deadlock issues)

Comment: For an example where it fails, create you're self `JTable` with a row sorter.  Using a custom table model, populate it from outside the EDT, allowing the model to fire update events.  You could also try and get two or more threads to update a text area (using random intervals) as a couple of examples I know

Comment: @Serg [no issue to simulating EDT lacks here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968)