# Running Java GUI application does not work from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: java, windows, swing, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I'm writing a Java program which checks some statistics of my Web site. The program should point out an alert if there are some issues with the site. Since I'm working with a Windows Vista machine I thought the simplest thing would be to create a Task from Windows Scheduler which fires every n minutes. 
Strangely enough, the Task Scheduler is not able to display Java GUI. The program just stops (either running with java or javaw) and does not display anything. 
Here's a minimal example:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class Test {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message text", "Title", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.out.println("Done");

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

I've tried also with some other Swing components but it just does not display anything. Seems it's missing the graphical interface.
Any clue ?
Thanks Max

Comment: How did you specify the application and arguments in Windows task scheduler?

Comment: Of special interest is which user is running the task. Maybe your program is showing the Dialog to `LocalSystem` or something like that.

Comment: I'm launching the program using a batch file which contains "C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\javaw" -classpath myapp.jar Test
I've checked that the program is actually launched (added a file log) but is unable to display GUI

Comment: @MaxKorn What is the working directory specified? It must be the directory containing the jar "myapp.jar".

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Guillaume the working directory was specified in the Task manager options. However that Java app starts, it just cannot display Swing GUIs :-(

Answer (score 2):

there are two issue

1. most important, [JOptionPane](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) block code executions untill event from JOptionPane is fired, simple this is basic property block code executions and waiting for users action
2. [JOptionPane must be invoked from Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), otherwise nothing happened, not is visible on the screen, [or (`MetalLookAndFeel`) only Toolbar without content is visible on the screen (came from Native OS)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Tried with the example in
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeAndWait%28java.lang.Runnable%29
However it does not display anything :-(

Comment: I'm never ever find_out the place for using `InvokeAndWait` (my view) in `Java6` and newer version, there must be another issue hidden in your code, maybe replace `JOptionPane` with plain `JDialog` could be dirty hack, but I'm doubt ...

Comment: To be honest, since I was not able to get it working, I have solved it by launching a browser new window (instead of a Java Swing GUI) which points to an Help Page. Thanks anyway for your help.