# Blank message dialog after exception is thrown

Tags: java, swing, exception, joptionpane, event-dispatch-thread

I'm learning Java, and I tried to make a simple client-server application. My server has GUI, and a button to start server. After it's clicked another thread is started. I call it main server thread because it deals with connections and handels clients. I also have button to shutdown server but not whole application. I close ServerSocket to interrupt this thread so I can stop server. I wanted message dialog to pop-up inf finally block to notify me that server stopped running.
Here is little bit simplified and modified code of server's run method:

```
public void run(){
    try{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"begining");      
      ss = new ServerSocket(TCP_PORT);

    while(cont){

       Socket sock = ss.accept();
       exec.execute(new ServerThread(sock));

    }catch(SocketException soex){
      //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"SocketException");
    }finally{
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"finally");
    }
    //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"after finally");
  }
```

First message dialog is shown correctly, but when some of other 3 dialogs pop-up due to exception I only get grey message dialog with title and window borders, but no message or any button. I cannot close it, I cannot close my application. It stucks there.

I'm using Ubuntu, and it compiled with open-jdk javac version "1.7.0_25", and run it using same version of java. I also tried version 1.6, and also Oracle 1.7.0_25 (both java and javac). Every time I get same result.

What is the problem here, and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this method run on the EDT? I suspect not. Swing is **not** thread safe and you cannot call Swing methods from just anywhere. Use [`SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) to show your dialogues.

Comment: OK, thanks. Changing JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"finally"); to SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){ public void run() { JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"finally"); }}); works

Answer (score 3):

- you are an issue with [Concurency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html), all updates [must be done on EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html)
- all [Top-Level Containers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html) must be created on [Initial Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html), valid for its derivates ([JOptionPane is derivate from JDialog](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html))
- see [here is demonstrations of your issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968), then application is candidate (is possible killing only) for TaskManager

Comment: Thanks, looks like I have to learn more about GUI and threads.

Comment: @Marko don't forget to accept the answer if it answered your question.