# JOptionPane.showMessageDialog doesn't show up after reading an InputStream. [Java]

Tags: java, swing, file-io, joptionpane

Here is the piece of code which I think is causing the problem.

```
while((is.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {   
                fos.write(bytes);
            }       

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Received.","Complete.",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            //System.out.println("File Received.");
```

Now when the control comes to the JOptionPane statement nothing shows up and the program won't even ends up. I had to end it from the task manager manually. When I tried commenting out the JOptionPane statement and used the console method i.e. System.out.println() to show the message it worked and the program ended normally. I don't understand why this JOptionPane is causing this problem. I am stuck here. Help would be appreciated. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: [event dispatch thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12643642/714968), more in Oracle tutorial - Concurency in Swing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to `close` the stream once you finish. It is working. When `fos.close()` is executed it notifies the EDT  and message is shown. In case of `System.out.print`, it is not in the EDT so it printed once `write` operation is completed.

```
while((is.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {   
                fos.write(bytes);
            }       
            fos.close();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"File Received.","Complete.",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            //System.out.println("File Received.");
```

Comment: Thanks man it worked. Can you tell what is EDT or provide me the link to some tutorial. Thanks in anticipation.

Comment: @essaji: Start with [*Concurrency in Swing*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).