# How to create a splash screen with progress bar in Java

Tags: java, progress-bar, background-image, splash-screen

I am going to create a splash screen for my application which is I coded. The splash screen should have progress bar, background image and info section which is badly needed because there are some files that need to be installed before application start to work, and I want to see them on the splash screen (like eclipse splash screen). Additionally, progress bar will move forward according to installed file. Anyone can help me about this subject? Thank you for your interest

Comment: You need to have progress bar on panel. Question seems very vague. Could you please be specific about any issue you might be facing in implementing progress bar?

Comment: the code will count the total files that should be implemented before the program is started and there will be a proportion between progress bar and with this total number of files. For ex: 15 package should be implemented before app. start, that 15 will %100 in the progress bar. When 1 package installed, the progress will be something like 6,5(100/15).

Answer (score 1):

Please go through some tutorials to understand how to use Progress Bar. And if you face any issue there then you could post your problem to this forum. Some good tutorials are:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/ProgressbarSample.htm

OR have a look at these answers
[How to add a progress bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916064/how-to-add-a-progress-bar)
[Progress Bar Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15199091/progress-bar-java)

Comment: I want a dynamic progress bar, I guess you didnt get my question ! @Rahul Winner

Comment: @ersnbck Progress Bar is meant for being dynamic. My point is, you need to be specific to your problem when you post anything to this forum.