# Custom UI in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to create a custom GUI in Java Swing? I’d like my application to be used on multiple operating systems, but I want it to have a custom and I don’t exactly know how to do it. Right now, I’m creating it using `JLayeredPane` and a bunch of `JLabel`s with icons. It works fine right now, but I’m having trouble making the application resizable(I want it to get bigger so it will be better for larger monitors), and making a progress bar. I know the way I’m doing it is crazy inefficient, but I don’t know what else to do.

I’m also worried that by using so many images will slow down the application and possibly use more resources from the user’s device.

Comment: Can you provide code? It might be best to break your question into two separate questions. Firstly deal with the layout issues here and for the progress bar look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916064/how-to-add-a-progress-bar) or create another question if that doesnt work for you.

Comment: I don’t have any code issues, I am just asking if my current method is the best way to make a custom ui for my swing application... I am using JLabels with icons on them, and I don’t think that it is the best way to make a custom ui...

Comment: The whole UI is literally JLabels with empty values, and icons on them.

Comment: Swing and JavaFX are both designed for cross platform development.  I strongly recommend you start by looking at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). You may also want to look at [Modifying the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/index.html), but personally, I prefer the system look and feel, as it's easier for users to adapt to something they are use to

Comment: @MadProgrammer I hope to have an option for themes so users can choose how they like it but I wanted to make my own first because personally, I hate the Windows 10 look... I mainly use Linux for that exact reason. Linux is faster as well...

Comment: Using a LayeredPane (I'm assuming that you're using one layer per OS?) is not the best way to deal with this. I would make the application work correctly with one give look-and-feel. After the program is done, then I'd worry about making it look great elsewhere.

Comment: @Amatsuki555 As a general rule - no - I find it easier for "user acceptance" to use the system's look and feel (by system, I mean the look and feel which best matches the system OS), but yes, it's out of date by  now